# Error in Initializing TextureView inside Service in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-textureview, android-camera2

I am getting error in initializing TextureView inside Service for Camera2 API. I want to capture Images with Camera2 API using Services. Below is my code:

**Camera Service:**

```
public class CameraService extends Service{
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;
private static final String FRAGMENT_DIALOG = "dialog";
int mPictureCounter = 0;
static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
private static final String TAG = "Camera2BasicFragment";
private static final int STATE_PREVIEW = 0, STATE_WAITING_LOCK = 1, STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE = 2, STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE = 3, STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN = 4, MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920, MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
        = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        openCamera(width, height);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
        configureTransform(width, height);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {
    }
};
private String mCameraId;
private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
private Size mPreviewSize;
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
        createCameraPreviewSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        cameraDevice.close();
        mCameraDevice = null;
        Activity activity = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
        if (null != activity) {
            activity.finish();
        }
    }
};
private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
private ImageReader mImageReader;
private File mFile;
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "pic" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + "" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + "" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ".jpg");
        Log.e("TestingProject", "\n\n\n--------------------------------**********************************\n" +
                "Files Absolute Path : " + mFile.getAbsolutePath()
                + "\n**********************************--------------------------------\n\n\n");
        mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
    }
};
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
private CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;
private int mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
private boolean mFlashSupported;
private int mSensorOrientation;
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback
        = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    private void process(CaptureResult result) {
        switch (mState) {
            case STATE_PREVIEW: {
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {
                Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);
                if (afState == null) {
                    captureStillPicture();
                } else if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState ||
                        CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                    Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                    if (aeState == null ||
                            aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                        mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                        captureStillPicture();
                    } else {
                        runPrecaptureSequence();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null ||
                        aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                        aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                    mState = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE;
                }
                break;
            }
            case STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE: {
                Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
                if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                    mState = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN;
                    captureStillPicture();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                    @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                    @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
        process(partialResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                   @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                   @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
        process(result);
    }
};

private void showToast(final String text) {
    final Activity activity = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
    if (activity != null) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth,
                                      int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio) {
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    for (Size option : choices) {
        if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight &&
                option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
            if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth &&
                    option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            } else {
                notBigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
    }
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
        return choices[0];
    }
}

public static test newInstance() {
    return new test();
}



private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                    = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
            if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                continue;
            }
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                    CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            if (map == null) {
                continue;
            }

            Size largest = Collections.max(
                    Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                    new CompareSizesByArea());
            mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                    ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
            mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                    mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

            int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            boolean swappedDimensions = false;
            switch (displayRotation) {
                case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                    if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                        swappedDimensions = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
            }

            Point displaySize = new Point();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
            int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
            int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
            int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
            int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

            if (swappedDimensions) {rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;}

            if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;}

            if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;}
            mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                    rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,maxPreviewHeight, largest);
            int orientation=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                        mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            } else{mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            }
            Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
            mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;
            mCameraId = cameraId;
            return;
        }} catch (CameraAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}
private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCameraPermission();
        return;
    }
    setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
    configureTransform(width, height);
    Activity activity = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try{if(!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");}
        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);

    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
    }
}

private void closeCamera() {
    try {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
        if (null != mCaptureSession) {
            mCaptureSession.close();
            mCaptureSession = null;
        }
        if (null != mCameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != mImageReader) {
            mImageReader.close();
            mImageReader = null;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
    } finally {
        mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
    }
}

private void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}

private void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
    try {
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }
                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {                                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();                                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,mCaptureCallback,mBackgroundHandler);} catch (CameraAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(
                            @NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        showToast("Failed");
                    }
                }, null
        );
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
    Activity activity = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
    if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize || null == activity) {
        return;
    }
    int rotation = Activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
    float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
    float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
    if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
        bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
        matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        float scale = Math.max(
                (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
        matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
    } else if (Surface.ROTATION_180 == rotation) {
        matrix.postRotate(180, centerX, centerY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
}

private void takePicture() {
    Log.e("TESTING", "taking Pic");
    lockFocus();
}

private void lockFocus() {
    try {
        List<CaptureRequest> captureList = new ArrayList<CaptureRequest>();
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            captureList.add(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build());
        }
        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCaptureSession.captureBurst(captureList, cameraCaptureCallback, null);
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.removeTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback cameraCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
        Log.e("TestingProject", "pic # " + (mPictureCounter + 1));
        mPictureCounter++;
        if (mPictureCounter >= 10)
            unlockFocus();
    }
};
private void runPrecaptureSequence() {try{mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
        mState = STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE;
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
private void captureStillPicture() {
    try {
        final Activity activity = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
        if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {return;}
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));
        CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,@NonNull CaptureRequest request,@NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                unlockFocus();
            }
        };
        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
        mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
    return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
}
private void unlockFocus() {
    try {
        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER,
                CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
        setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
        mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,mBackgroundHandler);
        mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback,mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        Log.e("TestingProject", "BHAND... " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
private void setAutoFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
    if (mFlashSupported) {
        requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
    }
}

private static class ImageSaver implements Runnable {
    private final Image mImage;
    private final File mFile;
    public ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
        mImage = image;
        mFile = file;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
            output.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            mImage.close();
            if (null != output) {
                try {
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
        return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
    }
}
public static class ErrorDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private static final String ARG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public static ErrorDialog newInstance(String message) {
        ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_MESSAGE, message);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setMessage(getArguments().getString(ARG_MESSAGE))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {activity.finish();}}).create();}
}
public static class ConfirmationDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage(R.string.request_permission)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(parent,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {Activity activity = parent.getActivity();
                                if (activity != null) {
                                    activity.finish();
                                }
                            }
                        }).create();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void requestCameraPermission() {
    String[] perms = {"android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO", "android.permission.CAMERA"};
    int permsRequestCode = 200;
    ((Activity)getApplicationContext()).requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);
}
public CameraService() {
    mTextureView = new AutoFitTextureView((Activity)getApplicationContext(),null,0);

    mTextureView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(), Gravity.CENTER));
    mTextureView .setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "proof_" + c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ".jpg");
    Log.e("TestingProject", "File Path : " + mFile.getAbsolutePath());
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                ((Activity)getApplicationContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {public void run() {takePicture();}
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }).start();
}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

}

**AutoFitTextureView Class**

> ```
> public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {
>
> private int mRatioWidth = 0;
> private int mRatioHeight = 0;
>
> public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
>     this(context, null);
> }
>
> public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>     this(context, attrs, 0);
>
> }
>
> public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
>     super(context, attrs, defStyle);
>     Log.e("TEST", "defStyle = " +defStyle);
>     for (int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount() ; i++)
>         Log.e("TEST", "IN constructor === "+attrs.getAttributeName(i)+"---- Value =
> ```
>
> "+attrs.getAttributeValue(i));
>
> ```
> }
>
> public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
>     if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
>         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
>     }
>     mRatioWidth = width;
>     mRatioHeight = height;
>     requestLayout();
> }
> @Override
> protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
>     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
>     int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
>     int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
>     if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
>         setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
>     } else {
>         if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
>             setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
>         } else {
>             setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```
>
> This is the stack trace of error
>   [image]

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the error. Without knowing what's breaking and on what line number, it is near impossible to help you.

Comment: I have shared stack trace in my post. I am running out of character length in my post thats why sharing the snapshot of stacktrace

Comment: Error is appearing inside the constructor of Service at line:
mTextureView = new AutoFitTextureView((Activity)getApplicationContext(),null,0);

Comment: You can't convert the application context to an activity like that.

Comment: How to do then? I have tried "this" as well, but still giving error.